# <script> tag is not working i am trying to run javascript script in script tag in html file

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I think its a basic question or mistake i believe i want to ask here (my appologies for being ignorant on subject matter) but I want to run this code from on of the java's reference book (JavaScript: The Definitive Guide
Book by David Flanagan) in a script tag in an html file. I sure it's probably a very little mistake, below is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>js book example1</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>test</p>
    <script>
        document.write("<h2>Table of Fibonacci Numbers</h2>");
        for (i = 0, j = 1, k = 0. fib = 0; i < 50; i++, fib = j + k, j = k, k = fib) {
            document.write("Fibonacci(" + i + ") =" + fib);
            document.write("<br>";)
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Tip: use your browser's JavaScript console, it will report any script errors and anything else that requires your attention.

Comment: Also, avoid `document.write` - it's a slow and outmoded way of adding content to a webpage (and it won't work as you would expect in callback functions or event-handlers), use the DOM API instead (`document.createElement`, etc).

Answer (score 2):

You have two mistypes:

- `k=0.` should be `k=0,`
- `document.write("<br>;")` should be `document.write("<br>");`

```js
document.write("<h2>Table of Fibonacci Numbers</h2>");
for(i=0, j=1, k=0, fib=0; i<50; i++, fib=j+k, j=k, k=fib){
    document.write("Fibonacci(" + i + ") =" +fib);
    document.write("<br>");
}
```

A very easy to find out what's the problem (for the next time) is to open developer tools (press F12, if you use Chrome) and navigate to the console tab. There you would see the line where the problem is and you could possibly solve it in cases like these immediately.

I followed exactly the above approach, in order to find out what's wrong. I didn't even try to read the code :). The console tab had the following. If you notice at the rightmost part of the image you have the exact line, where the error emerged.

[image]

If you now click at the line (js:14), you will see the following:

[image]

By correcting this and start from the start you will notice the second error by following the same procedure.

Comment: `k=0.` should be `k=0,`

Comment: @Phil Thank you very much :) My mistypo this time !

Comment: Thanks a million, i knew it was a typo somewhere that i was going crazy, lol , thanks

Comment: @Christos, sorry I forgot all about the chrome developer tool , thanks for reminding me, i'll keep in mind next time

Answer (score 1):

You currently have two typos within your code that will throw off the syntax and thus cause your code not to work as expected :

```
// You had a period here instead of a comma (after "k=0"), which will cause
// the remainder of your for loop to not be properly parsed
for (i = 0, j = 1, k = 0, fib = 0; i < 50; i++, fib = j + k, j = k, k = fib) { ... }
```

and :

```
// This was previously document.write("<br>";), note the transposed ";)" which should be
// ");"
document.write("<br>";)
```

**Example**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>js book example1</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>test</p>
  <script>
    document.write("<h2>Table of Fibonacci Numbers</h2>");
    for (i = 0, j = 1, k = 0, fib = 0; i < 50; i++, fib = j + k, j = k, k = fib) {
      document.write("Fibonacci(" + i + ") =" + fib);
      document.write("<br>");
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks i appreciate that